# Make notification drawer resume app when clicked

Tags: android, push-notification, callback, notifications, onclick

I don't know what the right term is here, but when a notification is launched, on the "notification drawer" (the thing where you pull from the top of the screen and see a big list of notifications from all your apps), there is your app's notification.

I want to have my app resume when this notification is clicked. However I don't see any relevant methods in the notification builder. Is this still possible?

My code:

```
private void launchNotification(Context context) {
    String notificationText = "Click to resume app!";

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_small_icon);
    notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    notificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(notificationText);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... with the notification intent your can open your app to the directed activity.

```
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
  PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

         notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to mesh quite right with my current code builder

Comment: I have updated my code. you can just add this and open any activity.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either... then again I am calling this from a DialogFragment and not an Activity, could that be why?

Comment: You obviously need a activity for the fragment to contain in. you can use a transparent activity for your dialogue

Comment: Seems to stack activities rather than go back to where you left off (hitting back button returns to original!)

Comment: fixed it using pendingintent flag PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT